# AWS S3 static website ajax callback fails

Tags: ajax, amazon-s3, static-site

Recently I got to the point to host a static webpage with a subscription option on aws s3 while website development is undergoing. My static web page makes an ajax call to another RESTful service with an email of a subscriber as a parameter. When subscription is done I need to notify a subscriber. Here it seams an issue with the callback.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://www.my-domain.com/api/Subscribe?email=' + email
}).success(function (data) {
    if (data) {
        alert('Thank you for registering!');
    }
});
```

After subscription is done ".success(" doesn't fire up. Response on the request is:

```
Reload the page to get source for: http://www.my-domain.com/api/Subscribe?email=john.smith@simplyemail.com
```

Does anyone know if it's an s3 feature or something else?

Comment: @theChinmay, unfortunately no, I gave up on s3 as a web site hosting.

Comment: Thanks. What are you using now?

Comment: When development is over it's going to be hosted on a standard EC2 instance.

Comment: Thanks @maxim. We also shifted to EC2 Instance. :)

Comment: Did you look at CORS policy? If I understood you are requesting something to another server, no to S3 (since it is static of course). Am I right?

Answer (score 2):

As per your description this seems to be related with [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) policy.

Look to ["why CORS"](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-cross-origin-resource-sharing/) as Amazon defines it:

> In order to keep your content safe, your web browser implements something called the same origin policy.
>
> The default policy ensures that scripts and other active content
>   loaded from one site or domain cannot interfere or interact with
>   content from another location without an explicit indication that this
>   is the desired behavior.
>
> In certain cases, the developer of the original page might have
>   legitimate reasons to write code that interacts with content or
>   services at other locations. CORS provides the mechanism to allow the
>   developer to tell the browser to allow this interaction.

I understood that:

> [...] ajax call to another RESTful service[...]

Means call to another server, and this may be blocked by Browser because of [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing).

References:

[Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)
[W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/)